# How to efficiently set values of numpy array using indices and boolean indexing?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

What is the most efficient way to use a mask to select elements of a multidimensional numpy array, when the mask is to be applied with an offset? For example:

```
import numpy as np

# in real application, following line would read an image
figure = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 4))  # used as a mask
canvas = np.zeros((10, 10))

# The following doesn't do anything, because a copy is modified
canvas[np.ix_(np.arange(4) + 3, range(4))][figure > 0.5] = 1.0

print np.mean(figure > 0.5)  # should be ~ 0.5
print canvas.max()  # prints 0.0
```

A similar question is posted here:
[Setting values of Numpy array when indexing an indexed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572482/setting-values-of-numpy-array-when-indexing-an-indexed-array)
but I'm using a mask and I'm not asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: Would you always have the open mesh arrays as arrays with sequential numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, it seems, is that using the arrays returned by `np.ix_` as index means you are doing advanced indexing, and, [as the documentation of NumPy states](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a [view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view)).

But in this case, if the real application is similar to the code you have posted (that is, if you really just need an offset), you can get away with basic slicing:

```
import numpy as np

figure = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 4))
canvas = np.zeros((10, 10))

# Either of the following works fine
canvas[3:(3 + 4), :4][figure > 0.5] = 1.0
canvas[slice(3, 3 + 4), slice(4)][figure > 0.5] = 1.0

print np.mean(figure > 0.5)  # ~ 0.5
print canvas.max()  # Prints 1.0 now
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to work with the linear indices. So, we would get the row and column indices from `np.ix_`, get the linear index equivalents from those. Then, use the `mask` to select the valid ones and finally assign new values to the data array with the valid linear indices.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
# Get the open mesh arrays from np.ix_ corresponding to row, col indices
row, col = np.ix_(np.arange(4) + 3, range(4))

# Get the linear indices from those row and column index arrays 
linear_index = (row*canvas.shape[1] + col)[figure>0.5]

# Finally, assign values
np.put(canvas, linear_index, 1.0) # Or canvas.ravel()[linear_index] = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a helper function that creates an appropriatly shaped part (view) of the array:

```
arr = np.ones((10, 10)) * 10
mask = np.random.uniform(size=(4, 4))

def get_part(arr, shape, offs_x, offs_y):
    # This example just does 2D but can easily be expanded for ND-arrays
    return arr[offs_x : (offs_x + shape[0]), 
               offs_y : (offs_y + shape[1])]

get_part(arr, mask.shape, offs_x=3, offs_y=4)[mask > 0.5] = 1.0
```

A ND implementation would look like this:

```
def get_part(arr, shape, offsets):
    slices = tuple(slice(offs, offs+length) for offs, length in zip(offsets, shape))
    return arr[slices]

get_part(arr, mask.shape, (3, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask=figure>0.5
```

If `ix` indices are really ranges, they can be replaced with slices as `@jdehesa` shows:

```
canvas[3:3+4,:4][mask]=1
```

If the use of `arange` is just an example convenience, we could use a two stage assignment

```
In [277]: idx=np.ix_(np.arange(4) + 3, range(4))
In [278]: canvas = np.zeros((10, 10))
In [279]: subcanvas=np.zeros_like(figure)
In [280]: subcanvas[mask] = 1
In [281]: subcanvas
Out[281]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
In [282]: canvas[idx]=subcanvas
In [283]: canvas
Out[283]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```